# D365 On-Prem Reporting Server Web Portal App 500 internal error

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I have this issue with SSRS web portal that it’s not working. I have restored a few AX databases and install updates to D365, but I haven’t touched the SSRS configuration or databases. I get this error in WebPortalApp:

`` Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!crypto!1!03/19/2019-12:47:09:: i INFO: Initializing crypto as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!crypto!1!03/19/2019-12:47:09:: i INFO: Exporting public key
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!crypto!1!03/19/2019-12:47:09:: i INFO: Importing existing encryption key
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!1!03/19/2019-12:47:09:: i INFO: Registering 300  : CsrfTokenValidationConfig
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!1!03/19/2019-12:47:09:: i INFO: Registering 500  : WebApiOwinConfig
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!1!03/19/2019-12:47:10:: i INFO: Registering 600  : ODataWebApiOwinConfig
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!3!03/19/2019-12:50:46:: e ERROR: [fz2yv91e]: fe80::6907:f912:7536:48e2%8: GET  - 0:00:00.0805311
Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Reports.AuthenticationExtension.GetUserInfo(IIdentity& userIdentity, IntPtr& userId)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost.Services.AuthenticationService.GetUserInfo(IRSRequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost.Owin.CustomAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(IOwinContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost.Owin.RequestLoggingMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext() ``

/ReportServer works fine

Comment: This looks like a configuration/setup issue, which makes it out of scope for Stack Overflow. I recommend you try the [Administration and Setup](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/765?pi68848=0&category=Administration%20and%20Setup) or [On-prem Implementation](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/765?pi68848=0&category=On-prem%20Implementation) categories of the Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations Forum.

Answer (score 0):

ReportPVMConfiguration.xml was missing from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\RSWebApp\bin".

I've found it in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin" and then copied it over. It stoers Data signing, data encryption and reporting services certificate thumbprints, so without the file, no account could authenticate against the portal app.